# how to set value for checkbox in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am a newbie, I want to know how to set the value for the check_box from '1' to 'Yes' and '0' to 'NO' in front end of ruby on rails?

```
  <%= f.check_box :RDSAP_Answer, id: "enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref_answer_check" %>
```

Now, in the browser, If I check the box it's store the value '1' to the database and if unchecked it's store the null value in the database.

I want to store `Yes for checked` and `No for unchecked` in the database. Is it possible to do in RoR? or is it easiest in JavaScript? What is the easiest way to set the value. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This can certainly be done, but may I ask why you want to do this?  You will have a much easier time if you stick with the conventions...

Comment: Thanks! Actually I have a Question and answer type and changing the answer fields depend upon the question like the answer fields are text_box and check_box. So, the check_box questions are like a yes or no question.

Comment: Why does it matter which values are stored in the database?

Comment: I'm not understanding, you can simply display 'Yes' or 'No' if that's what you really need.  Why do you need to actually store the strings 'Yes' and 'No'?

Comment: Because I am displaying the values stored in the database in the table in different page.

Comment: Don't display the values in the database - display what you want the user to see!

Comment: Okie. I am newbie... so just stucking with the plans.. Any example would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should leave the checkbox values intact and just use a helper to display the value as needed:

```
Answered: <%= object.RDSAP_answer ? 'Yes' : 'No' %>
```

If you need this often, add a method to the model for this:

```
def display_RDSAP_answer
  RDSAP_answer ? 'Yes' : 'No'
end
```

And in your view:

```
Answered: <%= object.display_RDSAP_answer %>
```

Comment: 'front end below' - what do you mean by this?

Comment: below the code of <%= f.check_box :RDSAP_Answer, id: "enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref_answer_check" %> in the VIEW?

Comment: If you want to display the current value as a string, then by all means add it there. But you shouldn't need to since the check_box already represents this - more likely, you should just add a label after the check_box to make it clear that the check_box state determines if it's been answered.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. But still am confusing. Am very new to Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Perhaps you should read a bit more about controllers and views, and try out some tutorials.  [Here's one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) to get you started...